# Odoo8 Warning : No such field(s) in model

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I would like to know some warning for function fields in Odoo Version 8.
I have a function field **amount_line_total** like that **amount_untaxed** in **account.invoice** model but I did not use this function field store=True.

```
amount_line_total = fields.Float(string='Lines Total', digits=dp.get_precision('Account'),readonly=True, compute='_compute_amount', track_visibility='always')
```

When I create Invoice, shows warning in logs like that:

```
openerp.models: No such field(s) in model account.invoice: amount_line_total
```

Is there any other ways for that warning not show again without using function fields store=True?

If you have any idea, please share me.

Thanks

Comment: if you add store = True the warning is not showing?

Comment: @Charif : Yes, if store=True, the warning is not showing.

Comment: Did you use this field in search or any other place

Comment: No, I did not use search for that field.

Comment: @ThaeEiHtwe generally this type of error occurs only when we have not upgraded our module properly because of some cases our database table need to require the newly added field doesn't understand. if you are updated it well then update the base module .